# BPMN 2.0 user task forms portability

Tags: bpmn

I have hit a hurdle with BPMN 2.0 portability. We have been using Activiti Eclipse plug-in for editing the schemes and to some degree it worked fine. Then we have hit an issue that boundary error event cannot be added in the Activiti Eclipse plug-in editor. So, we have tried to use Camunda Eclipse plug-in and we were able to add the error boundary event.

We use the Activiti engine to actually execute these scenarios.

Now, using those two editors, I have noticed the way they represent user task forms are different:

```xml
<userTask id="usertask3" activiti:formKey="choice" name="handle error">
  <extensionElements>
    <!-- This is produced by Activiti Eclipse plug-in editor. -->
    <activiti:formProperty id="ut" name="ut" type="string" variable="ut">
      <activiti:value id="u0" name="u0"/>
      <activiti:value id="u1" name="u1"/>
      <activiti:value id="u2" name="u2"/>
    </activiti:formProperty>
    <!-- This is produced by Camunda Eclipse plug-in editor.  -->
    <activiti:formData>
      <activiti:formField id="nextAction" label="Next action" type="string">
        <activiti:properties>
          <activiti:property id="task1" value="task1"/>
          <activiti:property id="task2" value="task2"/>
          <activiti:property id="task3" value="task3"/>
        </activiti:properties>
      </activiti:formField>
    </activiti:formData>
  </extensionElements>
  <incoming>_5</incoming>
  <incoming>_10</incoming>
  <incoming>_12</incoming>
  <outgoing>_8</outgoing>
</userTask>
```

It seems to me that the Activiti engine ignores what Camunda Eclipse plug-in editor saves.

I am confused as to why are there two different representations for user forms? Is this not standardized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User forms are not part of BPMN standard.

As you can see tags related to forms are located under `extensionElements` tag and are belonging to the specific namespace used with the prefix `activiti`.

`extensionElements` tag is part of BPMN standard (see section 8.2.3 of BPMN standard 2.0.2 or [XML schema](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100501/Semantic.xsd)) and its purpose is to allow vendor specific extension to the standard (such as forms).

A Camunda is a fork of Activiti I assume that they might have done some modification in those specific extensions points leading to some incompatibilities.